# oracle 'imp' utility returns result code 3

Tags: java, oracle, ant

We are using the following piece of ant build file to restore an oracle dump.

```
<exec executable="imp" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="system/passwordOfSystem" fromuser="myuser" touser="myuser" file="path_to_dump_file"/>
</exec>
```

When this gets executed it's failing giving the below result.

```
     [exec] About to enable constraints...
     [exec] Import terminated successfully with warnings.

BUILD FAILED
build.xml:: The following error occurred while executing this line:
build.xml:: The following error occurred while executing this line:
build.xml:: exec returned: 3
```

I know setting failonerror="false" will get rid of the issue. But don't want to do that since it would mean it will never fail (even if the dump is corrupt for example). Any ideas what this result code means ?

Comment: what were the warnings?  there is an option to supress some .. ignore=y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed like password was about to expire and it was complaining about that via returning the result code of '3'. Changing the password made the issue go away.

```
[exec] IMP-00058: ORACLE error 28002 encountered
[exec] ORA-28002: the password will expire within 5 days
```